# Python get stdout as a list

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

Here is my code :

```
rows = subprocess.check_output("ls -1t | grep 'syslogdmz'", shell=True)
```

The result i get is 2 names of files, but i don't understand why it doesn't put them in a list. Is there a way to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `rows.splitlines()` to get a list of byte strings instead of one string containing some \n.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `os.popen`:

```
from os import popen
rows = popen("ls -1t | grep 'syslogdmz'","r").readlines()
```

`rows` will contain the result in a list.

Comment: That seems to work, don't you know how to avoid taking the \n without having to rstrip it for each line. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

"Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string."

Not sure why you expect to get a list.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the manual page.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> help(subprocess.check_output)
Help on function check_output in module subprocess:

check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

    If the exit code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.  The
    CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
    attribute and output in the output attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    >>> check_output(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"])
    'crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 18  2007 /dev/null\n'

    The stdout argument is not allowed as it is used internally.
    To capture standard error in the result, use stderr=STDOUT.

    >>> check_output(["/bin/sh", "-c",
    ...               "ls -l non_existent_file ; exit 0"],
    ...              stderr=STDOUT)
    'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'

>>>
```

Try using `os.popen` to get the output in the list.
Or alternately use split() to get into list.

```
x = os.popen('ls -1t | grep syslogdmz').readlines()
print x
```